# How to insert blank or none between old array members

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array `[1,2,3]` so I need to fill some blanks or none values between it.

Such as `[1,2,3]`  to `[1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0]`from example I need to insert 5 none values between old member. (**the zero number represent to blank or none values.)**

So how should I code to do like this ?, some loops with `append()` or something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage assigning to the slice:

```
lst = [1,2,3]

newlst = [0] * len(lst) * 6
newlst[::6] = lst

print(newlst)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append(i)
    y.extend([0]*5)
```

First it appends the element of x itself, then it appends as many 0s as you specify (replace the number 5 with your desired quantity).

Result:

```
>>> y
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function takes `list` and number of `0` you want to add in between.

Try this,

```
>>> def fill_n(arr,n):
    temp = []
    for el in arr:
        temp+=[el]+[0]*n
    return temp
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> fill_n(l,5)

[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```py
l = [1,2,3]
[num if not idx else 0 for num in l for idx in range(6)]
```

?